# How to undo my redirect action in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, redirect, url-routing

I've redirected `/admin/kurslar/create` path to `/admin/kurslar/qoshish`.

And then, I've deleted redirect code section. But redirect function is not canceled. My question is how can I undo redirect method?

My web routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/kurs', 'PagesController@getKurs');
    Route::get('/tadbirlar', 'PagesController@getTadbirlar');
    Route::get('/blog', 'PagesController@getBlog');
    Route::get('/kurslar', 'PagesController@getKurslar');
    Route::get('/biz-haqimizda', 'PagesController@getBiz_haqimizda');
    Route::get('/aloqa', 'PagesController@getAloqa');
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getWelcome');

    Route::resource('/admin/kurslar', 'KurslarController');
    Route::get('/admin/kurslar/create', function () {
        return redirect('/admin/kurslar/qoshish');
    });

    Route::resource('/admin/kategoriyalar/kategoriya-qoshish', 'KategoriyalarController');
    Route::resource('/admin/teglar/teg-qoshish', 'TeglarController');
});
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Kurslar;

use Session;

class KurslarController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin/kurslar/index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $kategoriyalar = DB::table('kategoriyalars')->pluck('kategoriya');

        foreach ($kategoriyalar as $kategoriya) {
            $kategoriyaAss[$kategoriya] = $kategoriya;
        }

        $teglar = DB::table('teglars')->pluck('teg');

        foreach ($teglar as $teg) {
            $tegAss[$teg] = $teg;
        }

        return view('admin/kurslar/qoshish')->withKategoriyaAss($kategoriyaAss)->withTegAss($tegAss);   
    }
}
```

I've used `php artisan route:clear` but it did not work.

Comment: you remove `Route::get('/admin/kurslar/create', function () {
        return redirect('/admin/kurslar/qoshish');
    });` and you are still redirected?

Comment: Yes. That's why I am trubling with it. I've restart server as well. But still it is redirecting

Comment: do you have a route cache, clear it using `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: if this doesn't work then that means you have a redirect in a controller function

Comment: @madalinivascu I've done this, but it did not helped

Comment: then you have another redirect somewhere else

Comment: @madalinivascu Hmm. Where Can It be?

Comment: usualy in the controller or the modal

Comment: It's quite likely your browser is caching the 302 redirect, although it shouldn't cache temporary redirects. As simple as it sounds, have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Nope yet. I'll do it now